# defaultdict raising KeyError when unpacked

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyerror, defaultdict

I have got **`KeyError`** while using [**`collections.defaultdict`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [**`.format()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method

**Shell execution**

```
In [1]: from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                                                                                        

In [2]: foo = "Foo: {foo}\nBar: {bar}"                                                                                                                                                                             

In [3]: default = defaultdict(lambda: 0)                                                                                                                                                                           

In [4]: foo.format(**default)                                                                                                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-799cab129cf2> in <module>
----> 1 foo.format(**default)

KeyError: 'foo'
```

I am not expecting a `KeyError` since I am using a `defaultdict`. Why this happening?

Apart from that, I would like to fill the `foo` variable with some default values, how can I do that?

Comment: what are you even trying to achieve ?

Comment: I hope that is also in OP. *"I would like to fill the `foo` variable with some default values"*

Comment: By the way, the `KeyError` is not raised directly because of the `defaultdict`. If you would simply do `foo.format()` you would get the exact same error

Comment: Yes, but, the `defaultdict` supposed not to raise a `KeyError` when we are looking for a missing key, and which is the purpose of `defaultdict`

Comment: Yes I guess it relates directly to shadow ranger's answer where in the code above the `format` is trying to do something like `kwargs['foo']` where `kwargs` is empty, while the `format_map` will do `default['foo']` and use the power of `defaultdict`

Answer (score 11):

Using `**` for unpacking converts to a true `dict` (or functionally equivalent unrelated data structure; implementation details galore) so the features of `defaultdict` don't get used. In this case, you can instead [use `str.format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map), which accepts (without unpacking) an arbitrary mapping, without coercing it to a `dict`. It exists precisely for this purpose (quoting the docs: "This is useful if for example `mapping` is a dict subclass"):

```
In [5]: foo.format_map(default)
Out[5]: 'Foo: 0\nBar: 0'
```

Comment: In what way does it convert to a true `dict`? I thought it just unpacks to keyword arguments.

Comment: @ArakkalAbu: Yeah, for folks who learned Python back in the Python 2 days, they'd never have seen it (it wasn't added until 3.2). It's not commonly needed, but your use case is the primary case where it's helpful.

Comment: @superbrain: C APIs that receive variable numbers of arguments can only receive two things: 1. A `tuple` with the positional arguments, and 2. A `dict` with keyword arguments. There is no special keyword handling beyond that. It's equivalent to every function receiving `(*args, **kwargs)` at the Python level; `kwargs` is *always* a plain `dict`, even when a `dict` subclass is unpacked to provide it.

Comment: @superbrain it does, but it only unpacks the keys which do exist, so on the other side of the `format` call all the kwargs  are packed back into.. . a regular dict

Comment: @ShadowRanger also for the folks who learned Python back in the P2 days, `%` just worked OOTB with `defaultdict`. It still does, but it did.

Comment: Do you have a doc reference about the *Using `**` for unpacking converts to a true `dict`*?

Comment: @Tomerikoo [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) "When a final formal parameter of the form `**name` is present, it receives a dictionary (see [Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping)) containing all keyword arguments except for those corresponding to a formal parameter."

Comment: @Tomerikoo: I can't find a statement directly to that effect. If you read around [the docs for receiving/passing `**kwargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), it's clear they're unrelated though. Receiving `**kwargs` puts all extra keywords into a `dict`; passing `**kwargs` provides additional keyword arguments. The input `dict` is unrelated to the `dict` received. It doesn't keep the original `dict` even when passing plain `dict`s; a plain Python function that receives `**kwargs` from `**somedict`, and modifies `kwargs`, doesn't change the caller's `somedict`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I couldn't find a doc ref, but, practically, Python converts to *true dict* :)

Comment: yeah well that makes sense... The `**` needs to unpack something, so the `defaultdict` is currently empty so an empty dict is being passed... Nice answer BTW! wasn't aware of `format_map`

Comment: @Tomerikoo Just stumbled upon Python's "fastcall" and "vectorcall" and poked around in CPython's source code and now I'm back to not believing that this converts to a true `dict`.

Comment: @superbrain: Yeah, the modern implementation details make things more complicated, but the end result is the same for this purpose: The function doesn't receive a reference to your original `dict`-like thing, it either gets a new plain `dict` or a virtual replacement for it.